# Spring 3 + Hibernate 4 Load different Tables from database into same entity class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have around 10 Tables with similar ColumnNames. Can I bind all tables to a single Entity class ? So, in future if more tables are added, no code change needed.

eg: Example, REFT_Table1, REFT_Table2 ...REFT_Table10 are the tables on Database.
When user selects any of the tables from a dropdown on jsp page,hibernate queries database loads it into REFTEntity class

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
@SecondaryTables({
      @SecondaryTable(name="table2", pkColumnJoins={@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")}),
      @SecondaryTable(name="table3", pkColumnJoins={@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")})
  })
public class TestEntity {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private int id;

      private String field1;

      @Column(name="column2", table="table2")
      private String field2;

      @Column(name="column3", table="table3")
      private String field3;

      getter and setter...
}
```

Comment: Assuming this works, if a new table is added, I would need to change code, correct ?

Comment: You need to again add the secondary table and its columns

Comment: aah, then this would not work for me. I need to go back to traditional JDBC Template